# Firebase restapi filtering

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning Firebase. I have JSON as follows:

```
{
  "All" : [ {
    "date_time" : "2018-01-03 03:30:00",
    "domestic" : "0",
    "f_key" : "",
    "id" : 2,
    "international" : "1",
    "league" : "0",
    "match_number" : "One-day practice match",
    "men" : "1",
    "odi" : "1",
    "result" : "Pakistan won by 120 runs",
    "series_name" : "Pakistan tour of New Zealand, 2018",
    "status" : "2",
    "t1_short_name" : "NZ",
    "t20" : "0",
    "t2_short_name" : "PAK",
    "team1" : "New Zealand",
    "team1_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/nz.png",
    "team2" : "Pakistan",
    "team2_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/pak.png",
    "test" : "0",
    "venue" : "Saxton Oval, Nelson",
    "women" : "0"
  }, {
    "date_time" : "2018-01-03 03:30:00",
    "domestic" : "0",
    "f_key" : "",
    "id" : 159,
    "international" : "1",
    "league" : "0",
    "match_number" : "One-day practice match",
    "men" : "1",
    "odi" : "0",
    "result" : "Pakistan won by 120 runs",
    "series_name" : "Pakistan tour of New Zealand, 2018",
    "status" : "2",
    "t1_short_name" : "NZ",
    "t20" : "0",
    "t2_short_name" : "PAK",
    "team1" : "New Zealand",
    "team1_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/nz.png",
    "team2" : "Pakistan",
    "team2_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/pak.png",
    "test" : "0",
    "venue" : "Saxton Oval, Nelson",
    "women" : "0"
  }]
}
```

where I want to get data `ORDER BY odi AND odi=1`,

I am  writing like this:
    https://fir-resttest-4e895.firebaseio.com/Fixtures.json?orderBy=%22odi%22&startAt=%221%22&endAt=%221%22&print=pretty

But it's not working. So, please let me know how I can achieve my desired goal.

PS this is my public URL for Firebase with no security for testing, so anyone can access.

Comment: You're missing `/All` in your URL: https://fir-resttest-4e895.firebaseio.com/Fixtures/All.json?orderBy=%22odi%22&startAt=%221%22&endAt=%221%22&print=pretty Note that you will need to define an index, and that the data returned will be filtered but not ordered (since JSON keys are by definition in an undefined order).

Comment: How can i add indexon in  child All?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data. If you can't get it to work, update your question with what you tried.